# Enable my node.js web app to save google map pictures

Tags: google-maps, node.js, pdfkit

I have a node.js web application which makes use of google maps. I want to enable a user to save the map they are viewing in a pdf document. I'll use pdfKit to generate the pdf document as it has support for images but for this, I'll first need to save the image of the map. I don't know how I'll go about this. Can anyone give me some ideas on how to do this - how do I save an image of the map a user is looking at on the server?

Comment: The storing of the map(-images) will violate the TOS

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would have to get the image file through [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), generate PDF and return the document to the user.

I would also take @Dr.Molle's comment into consideration if you plan to actually store the images in a database.